# Mirror Modifier

Tags: modeling

I was watching blender guru model the SOBORG Chair and I wanted to do it too, so as I was following up I came cross the part where he uses the "Mirror Modifier" to somehow place another duplicate of the original mesh inside it, although every time I do it it "mirrors" it in a different position than what Blender guru has on his blender page[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default the Mirror modifier mirrors the object in relation to the object's origin, as if the mirror 'plane' is placed on the origin.
You can change the position of the origin to change the position of the mirror 'plane'. There's also the option to use a different object as reference for the mirror modifier, which I find much easier to adjust. Create a different object (an empty is probably best for this type of thing) and in the mirror modifier, in the "mirror object' field, choose the empty. Then, as you move the empty around, the mirror 'plane' will move along with it.

[image]